When you use the subjunctive tense for events that have happened?

Mientras, el valor de mercado de Nvidia cayó en la última semana de
agosto un 7,7% hasta los 2,92 billones de dólares, después de que
proyectara márgenes brutos en el tercer trimestre por debajo de las estimaciones del mercado e informara ingresos que solo
cumplieron las expectativas, decepcionando a los inversores que
esperaban resultados más sólidos.

They did project gross margins and did update their earnings so I don’t understand why the subjunctive was used here. Is it subjunctive because those things might have caused the fall in price?

In journalistic language, the imperfect subjunctive (proyectara, informara) can be used instead of the indicative perfect simple past (proyectó, informó) or pluscuamperfecto (había proyectado, había informado), as we can read under 24.2i here:

Así, adquirieran significa ‘habían adquirido’ (o bien ‘hubieran adquirido’) en el texto siguiente: Había contado con el éxito de operaciones bien preparadas, y con las posiciones que adquirieran sus hijos (Galdós, León Roch). La extensión tuvo éxito, y hoy es frecuente en la lengua literaria —y más aún en la periodística y la ensayística— de casi todos los países hispanohablantes. Se suele entender que cantara pertenece aquí propiamente al paradigma del indicativo, de acuerdo con la distinción introducida en el § 24.1d. En los textos siguientes aparece este uso de cantara en oraciones de relativo:


Era en ese santuario en donde Uriel había sido bautizado y en el que recibiera su primera comunión (Velasco Piña, Regina); […] el sobre negro […] que apareciera, inopinadamente, sobre mi mesa de trabajo y que aún no me he resuelto a abrir (Andahazi, Piadosas); Yo no creo lo que dijo Cereijo, el que fuera ministro de Economía y organizador de la Fundación Eva Perón (Posse, Pasión); Lo que empezara como Semana de Cine Religioso y derivara después a “Cine Religioso y de Valores Humanos”, se quedó, a la postre en estos últimos (País [Esp.] 5/5/1976); La oscuridad y el silencio producían en su ánimo una congoja, una tristeza, parecida a la que sintiera ese mismo día por la siesta (Casaccia, Babosa).

This use of the subjunctive is considered by some grammarians as a "covert indicative" form.
While in relative clauses like the ones above the imperfect subjunctive does sound literary or journalistic, in time clauses like the ones in the question this tense seems to be more common. In all cases, it can be replaced with the perfect simple past or pluscuamperfecto:

Mientras, el valor de mercado de Nvidia cayó en la última semana de agosto un 7,7% hasta los 2,92 billones de dólares, después de que proyectara/proyectó/había proyectado márgenes brutos en el tercer trimestre por debajo de las estimaciones del mercado e informara/informó/(y) había informado ingresos que solo cumplieron las expectativas, decepcionando a los inversores que esperaban resultados más sólidos.


This use is a remnant of the old meaning of the -ara/-iera form of the imperfect past subjunctive tense. Originally, this form was not subjunctive, but the pluperfect; the current Portuguese pluperfect still has this form.
So, in this case, the imperfect subjunctive has an indicative value and it means that the action is, not only in the past for us, but was also in the past when the main action happened. In your example, both proyectara and informara refer to actions that happened before cayó. This is: Nvidia projected lower gross margins, informed about low income, and afterwards its stock fell.
This is one of the very few cases (right now, I cannot think of any other) where both forms of the imperfect subjunctive are not equivalent: you must use the -ara/-iera form and not the -ase/-iese form.
Additionally, if you want to talk about actions that are in the past for us, but in the future when the main action happened, you can use the conditional, as in this example (based on yours):

Nvidia proyectó márgenes brutos en el tercer trimestre por debajo de las estimaciones del mercado e informó ingresos que solo cumplieron las expectativas, decepcionando a los inversores que esperaban resultados más sólidos, lo que haría caer el valor de mercado de Nvidia en la última semana de agosto un 7,7% hasta los 2,92 billones de dólares.


Como complemento a la respuesta que escribiera @Gustavson, puede comprobarse que ese uso es muy habitual cuando se relatan hechos.
Basta buscar "después de que" Colón "descubriera América".
Aunque Google ya no ofrece el número de resultados :-/, se observa que aparece frecuentemente.

Google todavía ofrece el número de resultados: se ve al derecho si haces clic en “Tools” (me da 3.920 con tu búsqueda).

Cierto, muchas gracias.

Nota: Google devuelve 3920 resultados de frases que contienen palabras de «después de que Colón descubriera América», pero por lo tanto no responde a la pregunta planteada.

Interesante razonamiento... o falta de éste.
